# CUPS: Restrict printer access to trusted users on network

Tags: networking, printing, security

I would like to share my printer (connected to my computer with USB) with my colleague though our network. I am very concerned with security issues and I don't want to do anything that could (potentially) leave a door open to hackers.

What is the safest way to share a printer on the network with CUPS?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned with hackers on your network like at a university or from the internet?

If your network is secure, WPA2 for wifi and not way to plug into your router for wired, you are totally safe. Just share it.

from an unseure network, (you have more to worry about then 12 pages of H printing but...)

sudo nano /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

look for

```
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow localhost
    Allow 192.168.0.X
 </Location>
```

X is the ip you want to have permission.

Comment: and how to limit number of pages?

Comment: @becko: Take a look at [Bifrost](http://bifrost.projects.linpro.no).